# Porque mi aplicación demora tanto al cerrar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño ejemplo en Python 3.8 y PyQt5 que contiene varias ventanas interconectadas. Pero una vez que intento cerrar la ventana principal esta tarda bastante en finalizar. Sospecho que es porque algunas de las ventanas secundarias se queda enganchada. Me gustaría saber ¿por qué mi programa tarda tanto en finalizar y como pudiese corregirlo? Saludos y gracias.
[Este es enlace a GitHub del proyecto.](https://gist.github.com/lrmendiburo/5abc28a2756a252c04afc22808e49ac3)

Comment: No conozco *PyQt*, pero quizás puedas ejecutar una función cuando el usuario hace click en el botón X (cerrar). En ese caso puedes probar a cerrar la aplicación mediante `import os;os._exit(0)`. La diferencia entre `os._exit(0)` y `sys.exit(0)` es que la primera cierra todos los hilos del programa. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo tendré en cuenta.